# Why doesn't SqlCommand.ExecuteReader() throw an exception when it gets a lock timeout error?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, timeout, locking

I have a table `FOO` with identity column `ID`. In a transaction I lock the row with `id` 1.

If I then try this line of SQL in SQL Server Management Studio in a different transaction:

```
select * from FOO with (updlock, rowlock, nowait) where ID = 1
```

...I get this error:

```
Msg 1222, Level 16, State 51, Line 1
Lock request time out period exceeded.
```

Which is good, because that's what's *supposed* to happen.

I have this testing code (error handling omitted):

```
internal class Constants
{
    public const string CONNECT = @"Data Source=.\TEST;Initial Catalog=TEST;User ID=YOURNAME;Password=" + "\"\"" + @";Integrated Security=SSPI;";
    public const string COMMAND = "select * from FOO with (updlock, rowlock, nowait) where ID = 1";
}

internal class Locker
{
    private SqlConnection _connect;
    private SqlTransaction _transact;

    public void Lock()
    {
        _connect = new SqlConnection(Constants.CONNECT);
        _connect.Open();
        _transact = _connect.BeginTransaction();

        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(Constants.COMMAND, _connect, _transact))
        {
            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleResult))
            {
                if (reader.HasRows)
                    reader.Read();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Unlock()
    {
        _transact.Rollback();
        _transact.Dispose();
        _connect.Close();
        _connect.Dispose();
    }
}

internal class Tester
{
    public int Test()
    {
        int count;
        using (var connect = new SqlConnection(Constants.CONNECT))
        {
            connect.Open();
            using (var transact = connect.BeginTransaction())
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(Constants.COMMAND, connect, transact))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleResult))
                        {
                            count = 0;
                            if (reader.HasRows)
                                while (reader.Read())
                                    count++;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (SqlException)
                    {
                        count = -1;
                    }
                }
                transact.Rollback();
            }
            connect.Close();
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

If I then create a `Locker` and a `Tester` and have the tester try to select that row while the locker has it locked, `tester.Test()` returns **0**.

Shouldn't the command be throwing a **lock timeout exception**, which the method would catch & indicate by returning -1? If not, how can I tell the difference between "no such row exists" and "that row exists but someone else has it locked"? Why does this work fine in SSMS but not in C#?

It's acting like the `READPAST` [table hint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx) is being provided, but we can clearly see in the code that it's not. Is there any way that hint's behavior might be getting set somehow in the .NET library code?

Note: I've tried this with every combination of isolation levels for the locker & tester as well as with a timeout period instead of using `NOWAIT`.

Comment: Have you seen this: [SQL Seems to Ignore UPDLOCK & ROWLOCK Hints](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d8de4f42-c9a6-4cbc-81cd-6ea5a5da3963/sql-seems-to-ignore-updlock-rowlock-hints?forum=transactsql)

Comment: @DMason That's an interesting thought, but we use `[SqlConnection.BeginTransaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86773566%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)`, which is explicitly intended to be used with the transaction inside the scope of the connection, while that issue was about `TransactionScope` which at first glance appears to be for one-off commands.